# Is it possible to have a python app authentication with a remote linux server?

Tags: python, authentication

The idea here is to have a python app, that when started, asks for a user/password combination. This user/password combination should be the same as the user/password of the remote linux server or in such case, and authentication system.

Is this possible? How? Which APIs can I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) and [python-ldap](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6988)